# ActionBarActivity items are not displaying, unused import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have been following a tutorial on Youtube that teaches how to use the Actionbar.  My problem is that the items on the Actionbar are not showing up on my device. In my `MainActivity.java` I imported `import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;`, but it says it is an 'unused import statement', although the person in the video doesn't get that message.  All of my code is copied correctly. I looked up some solutions such as making changes to the build.gradle dependencies, syncing project with gradle files, but no luck. If I could get my import statement to be used I think that would solve the problem. I **do** have Android Support Repository and Android Support Library installed on my SDK Manager. If you can scan through my code and spot my mistake I would be grateful.

My code compiles and runs on my Android 4.1.2 Phone (API 16), but the action bar items do not show up and I get this long error message which starts with this (I can post full error message if needed):

```
08-15 08:18:35.243  20311-20311/com.example.babbu.menuexamples E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.babbu.menuexamples/com.example.babbu.menuexamples.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Code:

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single"></group>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:icon="@drawable/sun"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/exit_the_app"
        android:title="@string/options_exit_text"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:icon="@drawable/night"/>
</menu>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.babbu.menuexamples;

import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;  //UNUSED IMPORT STATEMENT. why?
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is my build.gradle file, if relevant:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.babbu.menuexamples"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.babbu.menuexamples" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20"
        ></uses-sdk>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: @Raghunandan, posted manifest.

Comment: post `theme.xml` also

Comment: try  `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >` in manifest for testing

Comment: @Raghunandan, I do not seem to have theme.xml. I am using android studio.  Do you want to see styles.xml?

Comment: just use this `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` in manifest instead of `android:theme="@style/AppTheme`. Later you can customize. Do see the link at the top of your post

Comment: Thank you, the link solved the problem. Thanks for your time!